# How can I pass a fixed integer value in document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, ajax, paypal-subscriptions

Here is my code. I want to use fixed integer value instead of "package_select". How can I do this...

```
<script>
      paypal.Buttons({
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
          // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
              amount: {
                value: document.getElementById("package_select").value
              }
            }]
          });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
          return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
            // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
            alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
          });
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container');
      //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
    </script>
```

Comment: I think they mean `value: 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
          amount: {
            value: REPLACE_WITH_FIXED_INTEGER_VALUE
          }
```

See a full demo at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client